# How to program 404 error in spring rest api?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, rest

Im trying to throw a 404 error for a spring rest api when nothing is found for an assignment, but it wont accept the exception im giving?

```
Warehouse warehouse = warehouseRepository.findById(warehouseId).orElseThrow(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No warehouses with specified ID were found"));
```

its giving me this compilation error:

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) X exist so that ResponseStatusException conforms to Supplier<? extends X>

This is my first time making a rest API, am I supposed to change the exception in some way for this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orElseThrow` method expects a `Supplier`:

```
Warehouse warehouse = warehouseRepository.findById(warehouseId)
    .orElseThrow(()-> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 
        "No warehouses with specified ID were found"));
```

Note the use of `orElseThrow(`**`() ->`** `new ...`